# Using Google maps in an android library

Tags: android, google-maps, android-library

I have a library which makes use of Google Maps. When I give out this library how do I handle the api key scenario and registration of the client app on my google dashboard for the maps to be loaded on the android app?

Is there a way that I don't manage the maps and the client using my library just does it?

Comment: You don't want to restrict your map api key, right?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to restrict the API key.

Comment: When you create API key from console, do not add anything in package name and fingerprint. Leave them blank! Now, the newly created Map API Key is independent of any package. It can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was pretty easy.
What needs to be done is remove the mention of the API key in the manifest of the library. And ask the one implementing the library to put an API key the  application module's manifest.

This is a very good solution as this takes away all the headache of management of the API key from the library and gives the handle directly to the user of the library.

Many thanks to Christophe Beyls for the solution.